# Program that prints star pattern

Tags: php, complexity, ascii-art

I have a program that prints the star pattern.

**Starr Pattern is:**

```
          * 
          * 
          * 
          * 
  * * * * * * * * * 
          * 
          * 
          * 
          *
```

**My code is:**

```
$n=5;

for($i=0; $i<$n; $i++){

  for($k=$n-$i; $k>0; $k--){
      echo ' '.' ';
  }
  for($j=0; $j< ($tot = $i+1); $j++){

      if($i==$j && $tot<$n){
        echo '* ';
      }else{
          if($tot<$n){
            echo ' '.' ';  
          }else{
             echo '* ';
          }
      }


  }

  if($i == ($n-1)){
      for($l=$n-1; $l>0;$l--){
         echo '* ';      
       }
     }  
  echo '<br/>';

}

for($i=0;$i<$n;$i++){
  for($k=$n-$i; $k>0; $k--){
      echo ' '.' ';
  }

  for($j=0; $j< ($tot = $i+1); $j++){

      if($i==$j && $tot<$n){
        echo '* ';
            }else{
              echo ' '.' '; 
            }
    }
  echo '<br/>';
}
```

My question is that how can I calculate the complexity of this code?

And also Is there a good way to reduce loops?

Comment: Looks like a Plus `+` to me, guess it's just semantics....

Comment: `good way to reduce loops`  yes `str_repeat` and `chunk_split`  you can see this example (a code golf answer I did) of what you can do with these 2, https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/171679/i-done-did-made-a-spaceship-maw/171820#171820 basically you could make one long string with the space or `*` by using str_repeat and then split it into rows with chunk_split

Comment: Thanks, @ArtisticPhoenix, I have seen it but didn't get any logic because of the code in a single line.

Comment: For example `function f($n){$s='';$b=str_pad('*',($m=$n*2+1),' ',2);for($i=0;$i<$m;++$i)$s.=($i==$n)?str_repeat('*',$m):$b;return chunk_split($s, $m);}`  [Sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/63fad88e64131201b5d8feeef170860e8fa3840e)

Comment: It looks nice. Can you please make me understand how it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> It looks nice. Can you please make me understand how it works

For example

```
 function f($n){$s='';$b=str_pad('*',($m=$n*2+1),' ',2);for($i=0;$i<$m;++$i)$s.=($i==$n)?str_repeat('*',$m):$b;return chunk_split($s, $m);}
```

Output

```
     *     
     *     
     *     
     *     
     *     
***********
     *     
     *     
     *     
     *
```

[Sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/63fad88e64131201b5d8feeef170860e8fa3840e)

Let me write it in a way that is easier to see

```
$n = 5;
$row_len = $n*2+1;
$output = '';
//pad $n spaces on each side of *
$default = str_pad('*',$row_len,' ',STR_PAD_BOTH); //is = "     *     "

//loop once for each vertical row (same as width)
for($i=0;$i<$row_len;++$i){
    if($i==$n){
        //do the center line all *'s
        $output .= str_repeat('*',$row_len);//is = "***********"
    }else{
        //use the default line from above
        $output .= $default;
    }
}

//now we have a single line that is the length squared so we can chunk it
//into equal parts, to make a square
echo chunk_split($output, $row_len);  //is = "     *          *     ***********"
```

[Sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/44f69816d63af15dca63e9c62a8ce31da6a726e0)

Basically we can create the `"     *       "` row by using string pad.  Because we can pad spaces on both sides of a `*` up to the length of a row  `($n*2)+1`.

Then the center row, is just `*` so we can use string repeat to the length of the row for that line.

Last we take our big huge line of spaces and `*` and split it into chunks (`\n`) on the length of our row we want.

Comment: Hope that helps explain it a bit better.  Basically were exploiting the fact that it conforms to a set pattern.  So for example we know if `$n` is `5` to do 5 spaces a star and 5 more spaces `($n*2)+1` So we can just use String Pad for that and pad 5 spaces on each side.  String Pad takes the total length of the string you want.  So it's the full length of the row.

Comment: I think your output is skinnier than the OPs.

Comment: @mickmackusa - it is.  I didn't put a space between `* *` the stars.  Shouldn't be too hard to fix, but it adds a variable in.  So I was too lazy .... lol

Comment: DEREGISTERED!!!! What have you done, you mad man! What causes a person to do that?!?  An occupational requirement?  Witness protection?

Answer (score 2):

Here's my array-functional spin on the task.  It is not likely to be faster than @ArtisticPhoenix's solution, but it provides the desired output without loop constructs or conditions. ...just different for the sake of being different.

The process generates a full-sized array of strings that "looks" like a vertical stroke of asterisks, then replaces the middle element with a horizontal stroke element.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/LHgsZ))

```
$size = 7;                                                     // circumference not radius 
$vertical = str_pad('*', $size * 2 - 1, ' ', STR_PAD_BOTH);    // row w/ central symbol
$result = array_fill(0, $size, $vertical);                     // top-to-bottom stroke of symbols
$result[$size / 2] = implode(' ', array_fill(0, $size, '*'));  // left-to-right stroke of symbols
echo implode(PHP_EOL, $result);
```

For improved readability, I've declared the single-use variable `$vertical`.

Output: (highlight the text with your cursor to see that the pattern has no unnecessary trailing spaces in any line.)

```
      *      
      *      
      *      
* * * * * * *
      *      
      *      
      *
```

*notice that I am not bothering to `floor()` the "horizontal stroke" element key, because php casts float keys to integers.  https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php